# tikz intersection points when line is extended

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a short line surrounded by a circle and would like to find the intersection points when the line is extended with the circle.

The code below is my MWE. I assume that the errors are due to the fact that no intersection is found because as a segment the line doesn't intersect he circle. How can this then be best solved?

Here is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{through}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (X) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A) at (1,1);
\coordinate (B) at (2,2);
\coordinate (C) at (3,0);

\draw (A) -- (B);
\draw[name path=AB] (A)--(B);

\node[draw,name path=K1] at (X) [circle through=(C)]{};
\path [name intersections={of=K1 and AB}];

\coordinate [label=above:$D$] (D) at (intersection-1);
\coordinate [label=above:$E$] (E) at (intersection-2);

\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can extend the line without drawing it.  The easiest way is to use the `calc` library. The `overlay` option means that the path doesn't add to the picture size.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{through} 
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\coordinate (X) at (0,0); 
\coordinate (A) at (1,1); 
\coordinate (B) at (2,2); 
\coordinate (C) at (3,0); 
\draw (A) -- (B); 
\path[overlay,name path=AB] ($(B)!10cm!(A)$)--($(A)!10cm!(B)$); 
\node[draw,name path=K1] at (X) [circle through=(C)]{};
\path [name intersections={of=K1 and AB}]
(intersection-1) coordinate [label=above:$D$] (D)
(intersection-2) coordinate [label=above:$E$] (E); 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image: intersection of line and circle]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{through}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate [label=x](X) at (0,0);
\coordinate [label=a](A) at (-4,-4);
\coordinate [label=b](B) at (3,3);
\coordinate [label=c](C) at (3,0);

\draw (A) -- (B);
\draw[name path=AB] (A)--(B);

\node[draw,name path=K1] at (X) [circle through=(C)]{};
\path [name intersections={of=K1 and AB}];

\coordinate [label=above:$D$] (D) at (intersection-1);
\coordinate [label=above:$E$] (E) at (intersection-2);

\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```